# Adding vertical space (\vspace) around custom environment

Tags: spacing, macros, environments

I have document with custom environment `myenv` which left margin is 4em.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myenv}{
\setlength{\leftskip}{4em}
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{myenv}

Vertical space should be here.

\lipsum[3-5]

Vertical space should be here.

\end{myenv}

\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

I want to **add vertical space around this environment - that is before/above and after/below**. Most straightforward, but at the same time labor-intensive, way to accomplish this that I know of is:

```
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{myenv}

\vspace{2em}

\lipsum[3-5]

\vspace{2em}

\end{myenv}

\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

Since I want to be able to change this vertical space without changing vertical spaces in rest of the document, I use macro:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myenv}{
\setlength{\leftskip}{4em}
}

\def \myvspacemacro{
\vspace{2em}
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{myenv}

\myvspacemacro{}

\lipsum[3-5]

\myvspacemacro{}

\end{myenv}

\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

Is there any easier and faster way of doing this? Ideally, I would like to set length of top vertical space and bottom vertical space for environment same way as I set leftskip value. Is it possible? There are 2 similar questions: [Proper way of vertical spacing before/after environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22589/proper-way-of-vertical-spacing-before-after-environments), [Vertical space before and after custom environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44616/vertical-space-before-and-after-custom-environment), but none of them seems to solve situation like mine.

**Simply put, I want to achieve same effect as I would achieve in HTML/CSS by using margin-top and margin-bottom properties.**

I also tried to add `\vspace` to my environment definition, but it only adds margin on top of environment and leaves no margin below environment.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myenv}{
\vspace{2em}
\setlength{\leftskip}{4em}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{myenv}

\lipsum[3-5]

\end{myenv}

\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should _never_ set `\leftskip` directly in latex, it will cause any nested list or display environment to be misplaced. Always use a list for this. Also you normally ant to use \addvspace rather than \vspace so the space combines with other display environments. (and you have loads of missing `%` at ends of lines:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?  Note that an `\newenvironment` has three mandatory arguments:  the name, the pre-code, and the post-code.  Also the line-ending `%` signs are often required to prevent stray spaces from being introduced (they are not needed for this example, but I place them there as a best practice).

EDITED in response to Barbara's comment and using cgnieder's suggestion.  I verified that extra space is no longer added by having the environment start at the top of a page.  Thanks to them both.

Further EDIT.  David correctly points out that playing with `\leftskip` is dangerous.  I tried to allay his concerns by defining it as a change, not in absolute terms, but that, apparently is not sufficient.  Thinking I will leave it to the experts, I will delete my answer... which I can only do once the OP unaccepts it.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\newenvironment{myenv}{%
 \par%
 \addtolength{\leftskip}{4em}%
 \vspace{2em}%
}{%
 \par%
 \addtolength{\leftskip}{-4em}%
 \vspace{2em}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{myenv}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{myenv}
\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: the starred version of `\vspace` will not disappear at the beginning of a *page*.  if a new environment beginning with (unstarred) `\vspace` happens to start somewhere in the middle of a page, it doesn't matter whether what comes next in the environment is a paragraph or something else; the space will not disappear.  (similarly, a starred `\hspace` is needed only if it's important to preserve the extra space at the beginning of a *line*.)  in general, the extra vertical space is *not* wanted when the environment breaks from one page to the next, and the space would fall at the top of the page.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. However, it seems that pre-code and post-code are not mandatory as you suggested. My examples in the questions didn't had those arguments (since I didn't realize they can be used) and they still work - obviously no pre- or post-code is inserted, but file compiles, so those arguments can not be mandatory.

Comment: I'd add a `\par` at the beginning and the end of the environment definition, load `lipsum` with the `nopar` option and remove the blank lines to see why.

Comment: @Rafal they _are_ mandatory! If you remove the blank line between your environment definition and the next `\def` you'll get an error because then `\def` is taken as post-code. Right now the `\par` is taken that is inserted implicitly by two consecutive end-of-lines

Comment: @cgnieder I am trying to comprehend your your comment about mandatory arguments, but I still don't understand why my examples are working :)

Comment: @Rafal I think cgneider is saying you were just "lucky" that they did not break IN THIS CASE.  Whether they break depends on what followed your environment, which should never be the case in good code.  By the way, I edited the answer to take Barbara's suggestion.

Comment: @Rafal your definition has `\newenvironment{myenv}{...}` followed by and end-of line + an empty line = two end-of-lines. TeX inserts a `\par` if there are two consectutive end-of lines so this is equivalent to `\newenvironment{myenv}{...}\par`. This `\par` is taken as end-code as if you had written `\newenvironment{myenv}{...}{\par}` => you were lucky

Comment: @cgnieder It seems I was very lucky indeed - I have created multiple documents with incorrect syntax and have not experienced any issues. But I always used at least 2 new lines in environment definition and after start and before end of environment in content itself, so I guess that was it. Thank you so much - I learned a lot than I have expected.

Comment: @Rafal Just try having an `enumerate` environment inside `myenv` and you'll discover why I suggested `list`.

Comment: see my comment on the question:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Good point.  Does my revision take care of that issue?

Comment: No, that has the same problem. latex assumes leftskip rightskip leftmargin rightmargin linewidth columnwidth and @totalleftmargin are all in the correct relationship: if you change one without changing all the others bad things will happen.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think I will delete my answer and leave it to the experts... except I find I cannot delete my accepted answer...

Comment: It's for the best. If the accepted answer was changed it would presumably mean @egreg got the points and that would be a disaster:-)

Comment: Resetting `\leftskip` is useless, it would be done anyway by `\end{myenv}`.

Comment: @egreg That's what I had thought, until I misunderstood David's concern.  So I guess it's true what they say about two "wrongs"...(don't make a "right")

Answer (score 8):

Use the standard LaTeX `list`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myenv}
  {\list{}{%
    \leftmargin=4em
    \topsep=2ex
    \parsep=\parskip
    \listparindent=\parindent
    \itemindent=\parindent
  }\item\relax}
  {\endlist}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{myenv}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{myenv}

\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

Adjust the parameters to suit your taste.

[image]

Comment: This works, but using ``list`` in this context is a bit bizarre and semantically wrong (in my opinion). Is there any way to control bottom margin with this solution? From code I can't tell how it is determined other than taking default value from ``list``.

Comment: @Rafal Why should it be wrong? It's the standard tool LaTeX uses for such purposes. With `\leftskip` you couldn't have a list inside your environment, for instance. The vertical spaces above and below are the same, what's specified by `\topsep`; if you want different spaces above and below (and I can't think for a good reason to), add `\par\vspace{...}` at the start of your environment.

Comment: I wrote that it was 'wrong', because my example didn't suggested that it was list - I used only paragraphs, not ``\item``. In my mind 'list' is something that have items, so using ``list`` when there are no items seemed inappropiate. Though it is good to know that \leftskip wouldn't work with list inside this environment.

Comment: @Rafal just as an example: the environments `quote`, `center`, `flushleft` and `flushright` are defined as lists internally. This may sound wrong but I guess the reasoning is that this way the spacing is consistent

Comment: @Rafal no. the list environment is not mainly for lists it is the standard display environment construct in latex see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47057/use-of-trivlist-and-list-in-defining-environments/47069#47069

Comment: @Rafal Not only the ones cgnieder mentions. As well `amsthm`'s theorems and proofs are lists, so that if you start your theorem of proof by another list, it remains consistent.

Comment: @egreg How can I put something like:  `\def\cards#1 #2 #3 #4 {\s{} #1 \ \ \h{} #2 \ \ \d{} #3 \ \ \c{} #4 }`  into your definition to achieve the custom spacings? And is it a way to define it as centered?

Comment: @blackened Not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @egreg I'd like to know whether I can define custom spacing (say top and bottom margin) for a macro like above. Or am I supposed to start with a new environment for such tasks?

Comment: @blackened I would never define a macro like that; however this is surely a new question.

Comment: @egreg You said that you would never define a macro like that. I very much like to know how you would do it. However, if I ask such question separately, I suspect that the moderators will reject it because it is too specific. So, what is the proper to ask such a question?

Comment: @blackened It can be a good question, if you make a good example of intended usage. I'd never define a user level macro with arguments delimited by spaces.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest you to use the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package to define your environment; the package offers you an easy way to control the vertical skip below and after and also gives you an easy way to add the padding to the left:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdenv[
  hidealllines=true,
  innerleftmargin=4em,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
  leftmargin=4em,
  skipabove=2em,
  skipbelow=2em
]{myenv}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{myenv}
\lipsum[3]
\end{myenv}
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's generally recommended to represent vertical space in vertical units, such as `ex`.  (the `em` is considered a horizontal unit in the tex context, even though one might still refer to an "em square".)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have used ``em`` in my example since my background is in HTML/CSS, so it is more intuitive to use for me than ``ex`` or ``pt``. Great comment, though.

Comment: @Gonzalo It works, but seems to be an overkill when compare with Steven's environment solution. It seems that this package by default removes indents and even adding \indent in front of the text inside environment does not override this behaviour. Is it possible to introduce indents here?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina This method seems to break down when embedded within a list environment itself. The `skipabove` and `skipbelow` do not work.